# Share Grails database with standalone Java application?

Tags: java, groovy, orm

In Grails I am creating "domains", i.e. classes with some fields, which are automatically mapped onto database.

Is it possible to achieve the same (or similar) functionality in separate Java or Groovy project?

I wish it to be compatible with separate Grails-controlled database, i.e. for example, to write desktop application to populate database.

Comment: isn't gorm standalone nowadays?

Comment: This is probably an answer I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Grails mappings are based on Hibernate ORM. hibernate is independent ORM rom map objects to DB. I think it will help you. See [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html)

Comment: Can I be sure, that class described in separate project will be mapped exactly the same way as in Grails?

Comment: In Hibernate I was using either XML config or annotations. Neither is required in Grails.

Comment: To be sure in this you need to analyze a little db created by grails, and then configure this by Hibernate.
If you don't want to use Xml or annotations, you can try [Cayenne ORM](http://cayenne.apache.org/), as said on main page - "No cryptic XML or annotation based configuration is required!". You will map your db using desktop app. (Or maybe it can do everything itself, I really don'r know exactly).